# Java - How to make changeable (by subclass) static fields of a superclass, but protect them from i.e. main()?

Tags: java, static, field

How can static fields of some superclass be protected from alteration (for example in main method), while keeping this possibility via setters in subclasses. As far as i know, making it private won't make the job, because private static fields are not a part of subclasses. Only thing I can excogitate
is making them protected and include those classes (without main class) in a package. 
Is there a simplier solution?

Comment: Personally, I think you should re-think the requirement, this sounds like a pretty bad idea in general. Your solution should work, though I again caution you to reconsider the design.

Comment: Why are they static? Why would a subclass have to modify anything that's static in a super class? This design sounds like it's going to be a mess/pain to maintain. You should post your actual problem so people can critique/provide potentially a better solution.

Comment: I agree with the other two: this is a terrible idea.  What would stop me from creating a subclass that changes the static variable?  That would mess up all of the other subclasses.  Please help us to understand what you *actually* want to do, because this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo.precious = "nothingness";
    }
}
class Foo{
    static String precious = "Precious data";
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    Foo.precious = "More precious";
}
```

And if I add a private modifier to the precious in Foo class, then I will protect it from main(), however lose the ability to change it in subclass as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no access modifier that makes a member/static/method visible to a subclass but not the package.

This is taken from [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a subclass is expected to override its super class' behviour, you have to stick to the OOD rules: You'd better make them variables non-static so that the subclasses can re-define them and override its public getters:

```
class Foo{
    private String precious = "Precious data";

    public String getPrecious() { return precious; }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    private String precious = "more precious";

    @Override       
    public String getPrecious() { return precious; }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Foo.precious = "nothingness"; // Compilation error: field precious is not visible.
    Foo.setPrecious("x");   // Compilation error: No such public method.
    }
}
```